# VBA - Doing Application.VLookup in all sheets and counting when matches

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a workbook with 82 worksheets.

I need to do a Vlookup in all sheets and count when I get the value that I need.
I did a code to count the number of sheets and start a "for" from 1 to the maximum number of sheets but it doesn't work when I refer this count in the Application.vlookup.

Here is my code:

```
Function NUMBEROFTIMES(lookup_value)
 NUMBEROFTIMES = 0
         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer
         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
         ' Begin the loop.
         For I = 1 To WS_Count
        If Application.VLookup(lookup_value, Worksheets(I).Range("A5:AB401"), 28, False) = "True" Then
        NUMBEROFTIMES = NUMBEROFTIMES + 1
        End If
        Next I
      End Function
```

In all the sheets I have to search for the value that I put in the "lookup_value" and the return is the word "True".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TRUE is tricky in Excel, as it may represent the positive boolean, 1.  Try changing "True" in your code to 1 and re-run.

A more isolated test would be to explicitly test if the contents of a cell containing True equals the string True.

e.g.

```
    =IF(AB3 = "True", 1, 0)
```

...or, conversely,

```
    =IF(AB3 = TRUE, 1, 0)
```

...and observe the outcome of that test.

If that doesn't work, is it practical for you to replace the contents in column 28 with something less unpredictable than "TRUE"?

Comment: I tested my code and if I use the vlookup formula without Worksheets(I) and use for example directly Sheet2.Range("A5:AB401") it works fine. But I need to look all my 82 sheets so I need to use the conter in my vlookup.